# If my response to a question cannot easily be written to code, should it be an answer or a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I've just commented on this question:

[splitting json object into an array, and assign other objects to each of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24632012/splitting-json-object-into-an-array-and-assign-other-objects-to-each-of-them)

I was really hesitating between an answer or a comment. It doesn't have any real code in it and I don't answer his question directly. However, I suggest a fundamentally different method to approach the problem that can be a very large help to the poster and solve his problem. Because it was such a different way of thinking, I couldn't write code to support it by hand, but it was a possible solution to his problem.

Should this have been an answer after all? And what is the rule for solutions to "fix my code" problems? Should something with code always be an answer and something without code always a comment? Should reasonable attempts at solving the issue in a different way, but which don't supply code be answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer doesn't have to contain code. Stackoverflow is not a coding service; it's a site to answer questions. Questions can often be answered without code, nay, *should* probably much more often be answered without code. Often the approach to solving a problem requires more clarification than the code that's used to implement the solution.

As such, if you think your answer is more helpful without code than with, go right ahead.

Comment: so should I delete my comment and post it as an answer?

Comment: In this particular case I'd post the comment as answer, also including the mentioned trivial solution by Liam as code sample.

Comment: As suggested, I've deleted the comment and rewritten it as an answer.